# Unable to read image as buffer in react which is stored as buffer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I stored 2 times images in different documents in DB. the methode to stomethodred was 99% the same. (i will note the difference in code attached)

Both of them were stored correctly but when I read them in client-side with react, one read correctly
while the other does not.

Server : (nodeJS , using express, mongoose, multer and sharp libraries)

```
// * Upload avatar 
router.post(
  "/users/avatar",
  multerUpload.single("avatar"),
  async (req, res) => {
       const buffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer).resize({ width: 200, height: 200 }).png().toBuffer();
    req.user.avatar = buffer;
    
    req.user.avatar = req.file.buffer;
    await req.user.save();
    res.send();
  },
  (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message });
  }
);
```

[In DB the avatar stored as binary data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziRvo.png)

Now the upload file from client :

```
function Foo() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const filePickerRef = useRef();

  const pickImageHandler = () => {
    filePickerRef.current.click();
  };
  const pickHandler = (e) => {
     let  pickedFile = e.target.files[0];
      setFile(pickedFile);
  };

  const handleUploadProfileImage = async () => {
    // In this Image upload i added custom object in order to avoid bundries issue
    // In other image uploaded i build a full object with other data so i even didnt mention content-type in request header
    const obj = {
      test: "its seems that in order to use multypart contnet type i must use multy type ",
      avatar: file,
    };

    await usersApi.userUploadAvatar.post("", obj, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))}`,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    });
  };


  const getUploaded = async () => {
    // this route get all data stored 
    const { data } = await router.get("62cb2b404e986b25cc73dc74");
    setImage(data.avatar)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div onClick={pickImageHandler}>upload img</div>
      <input
        onChange={pickHandler}
        ref={filePickerRef}
        type="file"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"
      />
      <div onClick={handleUploadProfileImage}>
        <h1> Uploaded image to DB</h1>
      </div>

    <div onClick={getUploaded}>
        <h1>Fetch Image</h1>
        <img src={`data:image/png;base64, ${Buffer.from(avatar).toString("base64")}`} alt="" /> // NOT WORKING IN THIS IMAGE UPLAOD METHOD
        <img src={avatar}  alt="" />
    </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```